# Install OpenStack using RDO packstack --allinone, got stuck at the prompt asking for Password

Tags: openstack, rdo

Install OpenStack using RDO packstack --allinone, got stuck at the prompt asking for password.

Which password is it asking for?

```
Welcome to the Packstack setup utility

Installing:
Clean Up                                             [ DONE ]
Discovering ip protocol version                      [ DONE ]
Password:
Password:
Password:
Setting up ssh keys                               [ ERROR ]

ERROR : Failed to run remote script, stdout:
```

I tried every password that I've ever set and none of them worked out. I also reset my root password using passwd and problem remains.

Anyone has the similar issue could you please help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several passwords that are used during the install.  You can see which ones are being asked for by saving the input to an answer file.

From here you can see you to save the answer file. 
https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/

```
sudo packstack --allinone --answer-file
```

This [page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch06s03s02.html) lists all of the passwords that are used for the installation.